# How can i use Arduino uno as stand alone Atmega328p MCU?

Tags: debugging, arduino, avr

I want to use debugger which is provided my atmel studio to walk through my program which i want to write in assembly or c but not in arduino script language.

P.S: i don't want to use visual micro because i tried it already but it doesn't go through my assembly code

Comment: `not in arduino script language` - The Arduino language is C++ with minor pre-processing to generate function prototypes for you. It isn't a *script* language.

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://arduino.stackexchange.com or the official Arduino forums (http://forum.arduino.cc).

Comment: For in-circuit debugging, you need special hardware like JTAG ICE or the AVR Dragon.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Uno exposes the RESET pin, which is all that is needed for a debug connection via debugWIRE. Alternatively, JTAG debugging requires (IIRC) the SPI and RESET pins, which are conveniently broken out via the ICSP header.

Comment: Hello nick 

I know that Arduino language is simply c++ methods and they hide most of the details of AVR and makeup so much space. Sorry if i spell bad 
Thanks mttrb.